# React-native: ”this.props.imageSource" issue

Tags: npm, rendering, react-native, imagesource

When i use dynamic image src, and start NPM, i get this error:

TargetModuleName"."this.props.imageSource",:message":"Unable to resolve module...

But when i put const URL, its works fine.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native';

import CustomImage from './CustomImage';

export default class ContentContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>

          <View style={styles.col2}>
              <CustomImage imageSource={'../img/shirts.jpg'} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.col1}></View>
          <View style={styles.contentBanner}></View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

//------------ CustomImage.js -----------------------
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,AppRegistry, Text, View, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native';


export default class CustomImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Image source={require('this.props.imageSource')} style={styles.Image} />


    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax is incorrect. It should be like below.

```
require(this.props.imageSource)
```

Even though you fix that syntax it is not going to work because local image sources can't be dynamic because they need to be compile on build. Because of this path to the image needs to be known.

You can read about it more on [Image Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html)